# Why is this for... in loop not working when trying to loop keys nested inside objects?

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I tried looping names of front-end developers nested inside of objects(refer to code) and when I printed it to console it says display is not defined.

```
var employees =
    {
        sales:  {
            manager: {
                name: 'Evan',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 41,
                salary: 2000
            },
            sales_rep:  {
                name: 'Cilian',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 24,
                slary: 1000
            },
            sales_executive:    {
                name: 'Joanna',
                gender: 'Female',
                age: 23,
                salary: 1000
            }

        },
        engineering:    {
            manager:    {
                name: 'Mike',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 39,
                salary: 3000
            },
            designer:   {
                userExperience: {
                    name: 'Amy',
                    gender: 'Female',
                    age: 25,
                    salary: 1000
                },
                userInterface:  {
                    name: 'Jenna',
                    gender: 'Female',
                    age: 24,
                    salary: 1000
                }
            },
            developer:  {
                frontEndDeveloper:  {
                    name: 'John',
                    gender: 'Male',
                    age: 27,
                    salary: 2000
                },
                backEndDeveloper:   {
                    name: 'Felix',
                    gender: 'Male',
                    age: 28,
                    salary: 2000
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
;
var display;

for (let sector in employees) {
    display = `${sector}: ${employees.engineering.developer[sector].name}`;
}
```

First, I thought display scope was within the  for loop so I moved display variable outside of the for loop. It's been like 4 days since I started learning JavaScript so I am very new to the concepts.

Comment: The loop runs two times. The first time `sector` is "sales". The second time `sector` is "enginering". I could not find either `employees.engineering.developer.sales.name` or `employees.engineering.developer.engineering.name`. The `developer` property only has `frontEndDeveloper` and `backEndDeveloper` but not `sales` or `engineering`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I wad just trying to learn for-in loop… Now I understand why this is a really bad example for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,
there is a concept about your "undefined" at "display" variable.

HOISTING (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Otherwise, "console.log" executes faster than your loop so you get this "not declare".

In the other hand that's a bad example but I hope
this could help to you as beginner.

**Think about few things:**

- How to implement it with "recursion"?
- Why is already printing manager name several times?

```js
var employees =
    {
        sales:  {
            manager: {
                name: 'Evan',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 41,
                salary: 2000
            },
            sales_rep:  {
                name: 'Cilian',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 24,
                slary: 1000
            },
            sales_executive:    {
                name: 'Joanna',
                gender: 'Female',
                age: 23,
                salary: 1000
            }

        },
        engineering:    {
            manager:    {
                name: 'Mike',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 39,
                salary: 3000
            },
            designer:   {
                userExperience: {
                    name: 'Amy',
                    gender: 'Female',
                    age: 25,
                    salary: 1000
                },
                userInterface:  {
                    name: 'Jenna',
                    gender: 'Female',
                    age: 24,
                    salary: 1000
                }
            },
            developer:  {
                frontEndDeveloper:  {
                    name: 'John',
                    gender: 'Male',
                    age: 27,
                    salary: 2000
                },
                backEndDeveloper:   {
                    name: 'Felix',
                    gender: 'Male',
                    age: 28,
                    salary: 2000
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
;


var display;

for (let sector in employees) {
    switch(sector){
      case "engineering":
        console.info('Sector: '+sector);
        //At this point, developer is a nested object too, so we have to iterate again.
        for (let category in employees[sector]) {
          let name = employees[sector][category].name;
          if(name) {
            display = `${sector} - ${category}: ${name}`;
            console.info(display)
          }
          for (let subcategory in employees[sector][category]) {
            let name = employees[sector][category][subcategory].name;
            if(name) {
              display = `${sector} - ${category} - ${subcategory}: ${name}`;
            }
            console.info(display)
          }
        }
        break;
      default:
        console.info('Actually isn\'t implemented ['+sector+']');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this code example… I will check this out

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the name of developer from the object and if frontEndDeveloper key will only contain single obect then you can directly get the frontEndDeveloper name from the object. Please check below updated code.

```js
  var employees =
    {
        sales:  {
            manager: {
                name: 'Evan',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 41,
                salary: 2000
            },
            sales_rep:  {
                name: 'Cilian',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 24,
                slary: 1000
            },
            sales_executive:    {
                name: 'Joanna',
                gender: 'Female',
                age: 23,
                salary: 1000
            }

        },
        engineering:    {
            manager:    {
                name: 'Mike',
                gender: 'Male',
                age: 39,
                salary: 3000
            },
            designer:   {
                userExperience: {
                    name: 'Amy',
                    gender: 'Female',
                    age: 25,
                    salary: 1000
                },
                userInterface:  {
                    name: 'Jenna',
                    gender: 'Female',
                    age: 24,
                    salary: 1000
                }
            },
            developer:  {
                frontEndDeveloper:  {
                    name: 'John',
                    gender: 'Male',
                    age: 27,
                    salary: 2000
                },
                backEndDeveloper:   {
                    name: 'Felix',
                    gender: 'Male',
                    age: 28,
                    salary: 2000
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
;
var display = employees.engineering.developer.frontEndDeveloper.name;

console.log(display);
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: This code will do what I want but I was just trying to learn for-in loop and maybe I used a bad example for that purpose

Comment: Yes If you want to work with loop then make frontEndDeveloper array of object instead of single object

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to loop over each sector in the employees object, but trying to access employees.engineering.developer[sector].name. This can throw error because, since you are using for in loop, in first iteration , value of 'sector' will be 'sales', then 'engineering' and so on.
So, essentially you are trying to access employees.engineering.developer['sales'] in first iteration, which is undefined. That's the error.

I assume you are trying to print the details under the 'developer' sector. Yopu can achieve this with the following code.

```
for (let sector in employees.engineering.developer) {
if (employees.engineering.developer.hasOwnProperty(sector)) {
    display = `${sector}: ${employees.engineering.developer[sector].name}\n`;
}
console.log(display)
}
```

To understand for..in loop better, please refer [MDN webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). They provide good examples.